# Scroll not happening for my Jlists

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, windowbuilder

I used windowbuilder to create a GUI that should be a contact list. There are two lists: one of contacts, the other one of numbers. when you select a contact his number will appear.
But, when I add a lot of contacts, the scroll bar does not automatically appear, as it does to my friend, so I tried adding a JScrollPane. Still does not work.

Here is what it was:

```
    DefaultListModel contact = new DefaultListModel();  
    JList contacts = new JList(contact);
    contacts.setBounds(22, 64, 186, 135);

    contentPane.add(contacts);
```

here is what I tried:

```
    DefaultListModel contact = new DefaultListModel();  
    JList contacts = new JList(contact);
    contacts.setBounds(22, 64, 186, 135);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(contacts);


    contentPane.add(contacts);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

then I tried addind Bounds to the scrollPanel as well:

```
    DefaultListModel contact = new DefaultListModel();  
    JList contacts = new JList(contact);
    contacts.setBounds(22, 64, 186, 135);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(contacts);
    scrollPane1.setBounds(22, 64, 186, 135);


    contentPane.add(contacts);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

when I erased 'contacts.setBounds(22, 64, 186, 135);', the list stopped working.

I also tried not having the last line,  I tried only having the last line and not having the second last line, I tried adding "scrollPane1.setViewportView(contacts);", I tried taking away the "BorderLayout.WEST" argument for all the other tries, so I basically tried every combination of "solutions" I could find on the internet

I have no idea what is going on and I have no idea how to fix it. All I want is to be able to see all my contacts by scrolling.

EDIT, SOLVED:

The problem was my panel was declared as contentPane.setLayout(null); therefore "BorderLayout.WEST" was unnecessary.  In addition, the bounds should be applied to the scrollpane, not the list. Last, I should not have used add(contacts) to the panel. the solution was:

```
    DefaultListModel contact = new DefaultListModel();  
    JList contacts = new JList(contact);        
    JScrollPane scrollPaneContact = new JScrollPane(contacts);
    scrollPaneContact.setBounds(22, 64, 186, 135);
    contentPane.add(scrollPaneContact);
```

I'm updating in case anyone have a similar problem.

Comment: Try Setting this property `scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); `
and also no need to add contacts List as you are adding the ScrollPane

Comment: `I removed everything that was not interesting for the question`, the buttons are irrelevant to the question. The label is irrelevant to the question. You have NOT listened to the suggestions given: 1) you don't need to use "scrollbar_always", 2) you should NOT use setBounds(), 3) you SHOULD use layout managers. Fix these problems and then post the code in the forum not on dropbox. You were able to post code the first time so figure it out again the second time.

Comment: I thank you for your help and I ask you to be less rude. I didnt have time to make the changes you suggested, Yoda asked the full code that's why I posted, and "not interesting"  was all the links to other classes, as all the functions/buttons are implemented. It is 3am AU so I wont spend the rest of my night here adding 4 spaces to every line hopping it works. If I was helping someone, I wouldn't mind clicking a no download link. So again, I'm very grateful for your suggestions, I'll try to implement them as soon as I wake up, but please don't be rude on this community.

Comment: My comment was more forceful because you apparently ignored every suggestion I made in my answer. When someone makes suggestions you should take the time to read and understand the suggestions, not ignore them.  As a newbie to the forums learn from the advice you have been given and spend more time fixing the code instead of posting unnecessary comments. The suggestions I have given you are guidelines of the community. By the way The time where you are is irrelevant. If you want us to read code then the code should be properly formatted and readable, the way it is on your computer.

Comment: @LauraMartins As a member of the community, you should be "accepting" the answer (by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer) that helped solve the problem so other members of the community know the problem has been solved. I notice you also did not "accept" an answer on your other question either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the policies for `JScrollPane` using proper constructor.

> JScrollPane(Component view, int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy)
>   Creates a JScrollPane that displays the view component in a viewport whose view position can be controlled with a pair of scrollbars.

For instance:

```
   new JScrollPane(COMPONENT, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

EDIT:

```
 DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();  
    JList contactsList = new JList(model);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(contactsList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Tried as you suggested, unfortunately it also didn't work. But thanks for trying =)

Comment: Exactly what I did. I find it weird that when I remove the bouds of my list is stops working/displaying, so I think maybe the error is related with that.

Comment: You don't need to specify the policy. The default is to display scrollbars as needed. The scrollbars will work as expected as long as you use layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

```
JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(contacts);
//contentPane.add(contacts); // get rid of this
contentPane.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

First you add the contacts JList to the viewport of the scroll pane which is correct.

But then you add the contacts to the frame directly, which is wrong. A component can only have a single parent. By adding the contact JList to the frame you remove it from the scroll pane.

Also, don't use a null layout and don't use setBounds(...). Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. A `SSCCE` should be included with every question.

Comment: I made my answer clearer by adding `don't use a null layout`. This was implied when I stated `don't use setBounds()` and `Swing was designed to be used with Layout Managers`. Scrollbars only work properly with layout managers.